# replace odd occurrences of a character using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which contains '#'. I want to replace occurrence of only odd '#' with something else.

For e.g. for below string

```
This is my string # This is my string # This is my string # This is my string #
```

output should be

```
This is my string # This is my string '' This is my string # This is my string ''
```

> Note : considering occurrence starts with 0

Comment: I think the example output is wrong. Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO1hO0/1). Result is `This is my string " This is my string # This is my string " This is my string #` if you need to replace *odd* `#`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
([^#]*#[^#]*)#
```

You can use this.Replace by `$1"`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cT0hV4/9

```
var re = /([^#]*#[^#]*)#/gm; 
var str = 'This is my string # This is my string # This is my string # This is my string #';
var subst = '$1"'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Can you please show how to use it with replace function? something like message.replace(regex, "<br>") to replace it with <br> ?

Comment: Just for my knowledge, any idea how to replace even occurrences?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex:

```
#(.*?(?:#|$))
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW9rL6/6)**

**EDIT:**

```
var reg = /#(.*?(?:#|$))/; 
var message = 'This is my string # This is my string # This is my string # This is my string #';
var substitue = '$1"'; 

var result = message.replace(reg, substitue);
alert(result);
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o6L6aszu/1/)**

Comment: I added it with message.replace("#(.*?(?:#|$))", "<br>") but it's not replacing. Can you please tell me how to use it with replace function?

Comment: @user1298426:- Updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to do this

`str.replace(/(#.*?)#/g, '$1"')`